Is this problem well-posed? In average, a car manufact. produces 7 defective cars a year. What is the probability of more than 1 car being defective?
I have been trying to help my little brother with his probability class lately,  but I am a lot rusty. I think that this problem is missing some information.
The full problem goes like this:
A car manufacturer is calculating how many cars have defective brakes. To do this, they are counting how many cars arrive at the auto repair shop each year with this issue. They have found that the average number of defective cars arriving each year is 7.
What is the probability that more than one car arrives each year at the auto repair shop with brake problems?

Should it be clearly specified the distribution that models the situation? or can it be assumed a Poisson distribution, for instance?

I would argue it probably should be specified, but absent that information an arrival rate problem immediately begs for Poisson distributions to me.

@PrincessEev Thanks for your comment! I just wanted to make sure and not mislead my brother haha, some teachers can be very strict.

It is well stated if we ignore different lengths of years, assume the rate of defects doesnt change, the percentage of cars brought to repair is unchanged, and the defects are independent. If one year some madman destroyed the brakes on 100 cars, two or more cars with defective brakes might be very rare.
